# Sizing images with different heights to all be the same size using flexbox and CSS while avoiding overflowing [SOLVED]

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

**EDIT: CHECK ANSWER FROM ME BELOW**

I'm having a problem where I need 4 images to be the same height (1 of them is taller than the remaining), but I can't seem to get this specific image to resize appropriately without avoiding overflowing.

If I set a fixed height for my image div, I get overflowing content. (not from the actual image, but if I expand the webpage enough, the text div below it will have its border overflow out of the parent div.

When I look at devtools, the container for the image that I want resized is bigger than the others, causing this situation to happen.

If I use align-items: flex-start or align-items: stretch on the product div, that space will just move position and not align the images.

I then tried to set a fixed height for the actual image, but I still notice in devtools that there is an unnecessary space between the image and the text below.

Here's the jsfiddle link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/xy79o8g1/7/

In the link above, the image for "Neuro Tech" doesn't have the same height as the others, leading to an uneven look and the text below it to also shift down.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NexGen Labs</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./resources/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <div class="navigation-container">
        <a href=""><img src="./resources/images/nexgen_labs_logo.png" alt="The logo of NexGen Labs"></a>
        <nav class="menus">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Our Mission</a>
              <a href="#products">Our Products</a>
              <a href="#">Meet Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="burger_menu">
          <a href=""><img src="./resources/images/burger_icon.png" alt=""></a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <main>
      <!-- Mission Section -->
      <section id="mission">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text-container">
            <h2>
              Powering the Future, One Breakthrough at a Time!
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container">
            <a href="#">Learn How</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div class="divider"></div>

      <!-- Products Section -->
      <section id="products">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="product nano_sync">
              <div class="image-container">
                <img src=".//resources/images/nanosync.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                <h4 class="product-name">NanoSync</h4>
                <p class="product-description">Harnesses the power of nanotechnology to bring seamless and swift data sync to the palm of your hand.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product neuro_tech">
              <div class="image-container">
                <img src=".//resources/images/neuro_tech1.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                <h4 class="product-name">NeuroTech</h4>
                <p class="product-description">Cutting-edge wearable device that smoothly integrates advanced neurotechnology and A.I to enhance cognitive abilities and improve overall brain health.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product bio_elevate">
              <div class="image-container">
                <img src=".//resources/images/bio_elevate.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                <h4 class="product-name">BioElevate</h4>
                <p class="product-description">Utilizes the power of biotechnology to elevate human health and well-being.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product intelli_grow">
              <div class="image-container">
                <img src=".//resources/images/intelligrow.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                <h4 class="product-name">IntelliGrow</h4>
                <p class="product-description">An advanced, intelligent gardening system designed to maximize plant growh, revolutionizing the way plants are nurtured and cultivated.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div class="divider"></div>

      <!-- Staff Section -->
      <section id="staff">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="introduction">
            <h2>Meet our Prominent Staff</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="staff-container">
            <div class=""></div>
            <div class="">

            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>      
    </main>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Universal CSS Styles */

html {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
}

main {
   position: relative;
   top: 7.4em;
   /* To offset text from the fixed header */
}

a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

.divider {
   height: 200px;
   background-color: aliceblue;
}

/* Header */

.navigation-container {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
   background: linear-gradient(-70deg, #C45844 30%, rgba(240, 248, 255, 1) 30%);
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 2;
}

.menus ul {
   display: flex;
   padding: 2.5em;
}

.menus a {
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   padding: 0.5em 1em;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #CD853F;
   border: 0.0625em solid transparent;
   font-weight: 600;
}

.menus a:hover {
   color: black;
   border: 0.0625rem solid black;
   box-shadow: 0.0625em 0.0625em;
   padding: 0.5em 1em;
   font-size: 1.2em;
}

.menus a:active {
   position:relative;
   top: 0.125rem;
}

.burger_menu {
   display: none;
}

/* Main Content */

/* Mission Section */

#mission .content {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
   background-image: url("../images/mission_background.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: 50% 5%;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   padding-top: 1em;
   height: 50.375em;
   font-family: "Orbitron", serif;
}

#mission .text-container {
   width: 40%;
}

#mission .text-container h2 {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 1.3em 0.5em;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   border: 0.0625em solid #A9A9A9;
   color: #CD853F;
   font-weight: bold;
}

#mission .button-container {
   padding-bottom: 5rem;
   padding-left: 25rem;
}

#mission a {
   padding: 0.7rem 5rem;
   background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #A4A5A7, #8A8A8B, #858A8B, #1B1C1D);
   border: 0.0625rem solid black;
   border-radius: 0.5rem;
   box-shadow: 0.0625rem 0.1875rem;
   font-family: "Orbitron", serif;
   font-size: 1.4rem;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #CD853F;
}

#mission a:hover {
   background: transparent;
}

#mission a:active {
   position: relative;
   top: 0.1875rem;
   box-shadow: 0 0;
}

/* Products Section */

#products {
   background-color: aliceblue;
}

#products .content {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: stretch;
   padding: 3em;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#products .product {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: wrap;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 2em;
   width: 45%;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0.625em auto;
}

#products .image-container {
   flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#products img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}

#products .text-container {
   padding: 2em 0;
   width: 100%;
}

#products .nano_sync {
   background:linear-gradient(#080E16, #464E5F, #777F94, #D9B489);
}

#products .nano_sync .text-container{
   border: 0.0625em solid #AC9073;
   box-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em #AC9073;
}

#products .neuro_tech {
   background: linear-gradient(#D7B9BE, #2F1A54, #2B359D, #7C77C7, #9EB6EB);
}

#products .neuro_tech .text-container{
   border: 0.0625em solid #29349B;
   box-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em #29349B;
}

#products .bio_elevate {
   background:linear-gradient(#464367, #9993A4, #636F8E, #1C253B);
}

#products .bio_elevate .text-container {
   border: 0.0625em solid #AF9DB4;
   box-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em #AF9DB4;
}

#products .intelli_grow {
   background: linear-gradient(#0A2718, #619C65, #619C65, #91A184);
}

#products .intelli_grow .text-container {
   border: 0.0625em solid #042019;
   box-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em;
}

#products .product-name {
   font-size: 2em;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 0.5em 0;
}

#products .product-description {
   font-size: 1.5em;
   padding-top: 0.5em;
   line-height: 1.4;
}
/* Staff Section */



/* Footer */
```

Comment: What height do you want them all to be? And do you want to definitely show all of each image Iin which case some may be narrower than others) or is it important that they have the same width as well (i.e. some may need to get cropped)?

Comment: The images should be as tall as their container, but my problem was that I was getting an unnecessary space between my image and text div, causing the text to shift down. This was because one of the images was taller. I managed to solve it with the help of the answers below. Still, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an aspect ratio for the images. The intrinsic size of the other three images are 1200x800, which is a ratio of 3-to-2.

```
#products img {
    aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
}
```

My original answer was based on the external fiddle you provided. I didn't realize that the CSS you showed in the question is different.

In addition to the above solution that answers your question, you are also concerned about a gap between the image container and the text container. This occurs when there is less text than other products in the row and is due to having flex on the parent "product" container (which stretches the height of these child containers to fill the product container.)

I am going to assume that you want the text containers to all be the same size and grow to fill the available space. You'll need to change the flex-direction and flex-grow. If you don't want the text container with its border to be wider than the image, you should also declare `box-sizing: border-box`.

```
#products .product {
    flex-direction: column;
    /* flex-flow: wrap; */
    /* align-items: center; */
}

#products .image-container {
    /* flex: 1 1 auto; */
}

#products .text-container {
   flex-grow: 1;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
/* Universal CSS Styles */

html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Products Section */

#products {
   background-color: aliceblue;
}

#products .content {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: stretch;
   padding: 3em;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#products .product {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   /* flex-flow: wrap; */
   /* align-items: center; */
   padding: 2em;
   width: 45%;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0.625em auto;
}

#products .image-container {
   /* flex: 1 1 auto; */
}

#products img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
}

#products .text-container {
   padding: 2em 0;
   width: 100%;
   flex-grow: 1;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

#products .nano_sync {
   background:linear-gradient(#080E16, #464E5F, #777F94, #D9B489);
}

#products .nano_sync .text-container{
   border: 0.0625em solid #AC9073;
   box-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em #AC9073;
}

#products .neuro_tech {
   background: linear-gradient(#D7B9BE, #2F1A54, #2B359D, #7C77C7, #9EB6EB);
}

#products .neuro_tech .text-container{
   border: 0.0625em solid #29349B;
   box-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em #29349B;
}

#products .bio_elevate {
   background:linear-gradient(#464367, #9993A4, #636F8E, #1C253B);
}

#products .bio_elevate .text-container {
   border: 0.0625em solid #AF9DB4;
   box-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em #AF9DB4;
}

#products .intelli_grow {
   background: linear-gradient(#0A2718, #619C65, #619C65, #91A184);
}

#products .intelli_grow .text-container {
   border: 0.0625em solid #042019;
   box-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em;
}

#products .product-name {
   font-size: 2em;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 0.5em 0;
}

#products .product-description {
   font-size: 1.5em;
   padding-top: 0.5em;
   line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<!-- Products Section -->
<section id="products">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="product nano_sync">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/G2L1742r/nanosync.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text-container">
        <h4 class="product-name">NanoSync</h4>
        <p class="product-description">Harnesses the power of nanotechnology to bring seamless and swift data sync to the palm of your hand.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product neuro_tech">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/bvHh9xq3/neuro-tech1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text-container">
        <h4 class="product-name">NeuroTech</h4>
        <p class="product-description">Cutting-edge wearable device that smoothly integrates advanced neurotechnology and A.I to enhance cognitive abilities and improve overall brain health.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product bio_elevate">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/GmDrH0V0/bio-elevate.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text-container">
        <h4 class="product-name">BioElevate</h4>
        <p class="product-description">Utilizes the power of biotechnology to elevate human health and well-being.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product intelli_grow">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/50sWZfYz/intelligrow.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text-container">
        <h4 class="product-name">IntelliGrow</h4>
        <p class="product-description">An advanced, intelligent gardening system designed to maximize plant growh, revolutionizing the way plants are nurtured and cultivated.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I've tried your solution, and while the images did align, there is still a space that as far as I can see still belongs to the image div. Here it is https://imgur.com/a/RHnDX5z | Here's the space with the help of devtools for easier visibility: https://imgur.com/a/BDps9dw | 
I did use align-items: flex-start on the product div and the images do align, but they still have this space left. Align-items: stretch was also used, but didn't work as well.

Comment: @StewieL I didn't realize that you posted different CSS in your question than what you have in your JSFiddle. The most significant difference is you removed `flex-direction: column` (that is in the JSFiddle as `flex-flow: column wrap`.

Comment: I did. I removed that declaration because they all looked "ok" to me, but I think that was because of the width:45% part of my code. 
In previous attempts, I had changed to flex-flow: column wrap but the most important part was also that I was using flex on the wrong container. When I tried your solution for the flex: 1 on the text container, rather than the image container, it worked.
As for the box-sizing: border-box, I thought it came in most reset.css (pardon my ignorance, still new). I'll try to be on the lookout for these small things. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use aspect ratio to detirmine the size of the container of the image and then set the image as position absolute. see [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8x15m7oy/).

The reason I set the aspect ratio on the container and then the image as position absolute with `object-fit: cover;` is because this way we don't actually mess with the proportions of the image. The image will retain it's own aspect-ratio but will be made to cover the aspect-ratio of the container by cropping the edges to fit.

I altered `#products .image-container` and `#products .product img`

```
#products .image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    aspect-ratio:5/3; /*This will set the aspect-ratio on the container to be the same for all boxes.*/
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#products .product img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; /*This decides how the image should be resized in the container*/
    object-position: center center; /*Specify the alignment of the image*/
}
```

**HTML Snippet**

```css
/* Universal CSS Styles */

html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

main {
    position: relative;
    top: 7.4em;
    /* To offset text from the fixed header */
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Header */

.navigation-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color:aliceblue;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.menus ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 2.5em;
}

.menus a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CD853F;
    border: 0.0625em none transparent;
}

.menus a:hover {
    color: black;
    border: 0.0625rem solid black;
    box-shadow: 0.0625rem 0.0625rem;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.menus a:active {
    position:relative;
    top: 0.125rem;
}

.burger_menu {
    display: none;
}

/* Main Content */

/* Mission Section */

#mission .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/k4XyhCPL/mission-background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 100% 5%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding-top: 1em;
    height: 34.25rem;
    font-family: "Orbitron", serif;
}

#mission .text-container h2 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.3em 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    border: 0.0625em solid #A9A9A9;
    color: #CD853F;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#mission .button-container {
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

#mission a {
    padding: 0.7rem 5rem;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border: 0.0625rem solid black;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0.0625rem 0.1875rem;
    font-family: "Orbitron", serif;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #CD853F;
}

#mission a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

#mission a:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.1875rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0;
}

/* Products Section */

#products {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

#products .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#products .product {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 250, 0.7);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2em;
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 1.5625rem;
    text-align: center;
}

    #products .image-container {
        overflow: hidden;
        aspect-ratio:5/3; /*This will set the aspect-ratio on the container to be the same for all boxes.*/
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    #products .product img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover; /*This decides how the image should be resized in the container*/
        object-position: center center; /*Specify the alignment of the image*/
    }

#products .product-name {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

#products .product-description {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

/* Staff Section */



/* Footer */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>NexGen Labs</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./resources/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <div class="navigation-container">
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/8CVGvKg7/nexgen-labs-logo.png" alt="The logo of NexGen Labs"></a>
        <nav class="menus">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Our Mission</a>
              <a href="#">Our Products</a>
              <a href="#">Meet Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="burger_menu">
          <a href=""><img src="./resources/images/burger_icon.png" alt=""></a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <main>
      <!-- Mission Section -->
      <section id="mission">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text-container">
            <h2>
              Powering the Future, One Breakthrough at a Time!
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container">
            <a href="#">Learn How</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- Products Section -->
      <section id="products">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="product nano_sync">
              <div class="image-container">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/G2L1742r/nanosync.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                <h4 class="product-name">NanoSync</h4>
                <p class="product-description">Harnesses the power of nanotechnology to bring seamless and swift data sync to the palm of your hand.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product neuro_tech">
              <div class="image-container">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/bvHh9xq3/neuro-tech1.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                <h4 class="product-name">NeuroTech</h4>
                <p class="product-description">Cutting-edge wearable device that smoothly integrates advanced neurotechnology and A.I to enhance cognitive abilities and improve overall brain health.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product bio_elevate">
              <div class="image-container">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/GmDrH0V0/bio-elevate.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                <h4 class="product-name">BioElevate</h4>
                <p class="product-description">Utilizes the power of biotechnology to elevate human health and well-being.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product intelli_grow">
              <div class="image-container">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/50sWZfYz/intelligrow.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                <h4 class="product-name">IntelliGrow</h4>
                <p class="product-description">An advanced, intelligent gardening system designed to maximize plant growh, revolutionizing the way plants are nurtured and cultivated.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Staff Section -->
      <section id="staff"></section>      
    </main>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So just to make sure I understood your code correctly: Use aspect-ratios on containers, not images. You then set position:relative on the child image container, causing its position to be relative to the parent container and width:100% to fill the entire image div.
Then you set position: absolute on the img and use top, left, right and bottom position the image at the center of the image div (is this correct?) and set height: 100% to have the image be as tall as 100% of the image div.

Comment: Object-fit and object-position are new to me but I understood what they aim to accomplish.
Was everything correctly said in the comment above about your code? I want to make sure I understand it completely.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Technically it's the object-position that centers the image but the positioning just makes sure the image will use all the available space of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this here because I got multiple insights from different people and for some reason, I can't set both answers to be correct.

The solutions:

Setting an aspect ratio, **flex:1 on the text container**, rather than the image container, and **flex-flow: column wrap** on the **.product** flex container.

Credit to [Tim R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21849374/tim-r) for this answer.

Setting an aspect ratio (**on the image container**), using **position: relative** (container), **position: absolute** (img), and o**bject-fit: cover** to make sure images looked good when resizing.

Credit to [Natalie Hedström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1434964/natalie-hedstr%C3%B6m) for this answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).